# Generate binary matrix from series of csv strings in SQL Server (2012)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Have a table of the form

```sql
pk items
--------
1  a,b,c,...
2  d,e,f,...
3  g,h,i,...
4  j,k,l,...
.
.
.
```

where the items column values are variable length (can be empty) csv strings (whose elements need not be unique) of, say, grocery items (just using letters here for readability).

From this, want to be able to generate a binary matrix that represents the items that any given pk contains, eg.

```sql
pk a b c d e f g ...
--------------------
1  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
2  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
.
.
.
```

Note that I also have access to a table that represents the entire domain of possible values for any item in the csv lists, eg.

```sql
item
------
a
b
c
.
.
.
```

Does anyone know an efficient way that this can be done?

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing delimited data in the first place. It violates 1NF and is nothing but horrible to work with.

Comment: @Larnu SQL Server 2012

Comment: @SeanLange I see. Not really that experienced with SQL stuff, but that is just the way the data initially comes in so far as I can tell, so it's what I have to work with.

Comment: Ouch!!! You will have to use a string splitter to parse those values into rows. You will also need something that contains all the columns because you will need to a left join to get back data where the column exists but there isn't data. How do you know what columns you want returned? Is that dynamic as well? This has all the makings of something really horrific to write and very likely the performance is going to be pretty horrid also. Hard to say for sure though as this is pretty vague.

Comment: @SeanLange I thought so that it would be bad. I had previously been generating the matrix by importing the csv series into a python Pandas frame and working with it there, but was taking a long time. The columns I wanted returned are the entire domain so can see what 'items' each row has. I am not the author of the domain table, so don't know how it is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with the comments made, and this is far from an ideal way of storing data. Your table `Form` should be normalised, and really you should be using your presentation layer to do this. I've written the below using `STRING_SPLIT`, however, you can use [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) to achieve this as well. (Correction, you will need to, as you're using SQL Server 2012.)

This isn't entry level stuff, so please do ask if you don't understand:

```
--Create the table with all the items
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item (ItemID int IDENTITY (1,1),
                       ItemName varchar(2));

INSERT INTO dbo.Item(ItemName)
VALUES('a'),
      ('b'),
      ('c'),
      ('d'),
      ('e'),
      ('f'),
      ('g'),
      ('h'),
      ('i'),
      ('j'),
      ('k'),
      ('l'),
      ('m'),
      ('n'),
      ('o'),
      ('p'),
      ('q');
GO

--And now your sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.Form (Pk int IDENTITY (1,1),
                       Items varchar(100)); --Really you shouldn't be storing delimited data

INSERT INTO dbo.Form (Items)
VALUES ('a,b,c'),
       ('d,e,f'),
       ('g,h,i'),
       ('j,k,l');

GO

--Declare the SQL variable to store the dynamic SQL
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

--Build the SQL. Use FOR XML PATH to create the delimited list of columns,
--STRING_SPLIT in the dynamic SQL to split the data
--and a cross tab to pivot the data
--YUCK (sorry)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT F.Pk,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SS.[value] = ' + QUOTENAME(I.ItemName,'''') + N'THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ' + QUOTENAME(I.ItemName)
                  FROM dbo.Item I
                  ORDER BY I.ItemName ASC
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'FROM dbo.Form F' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(F.Items,'','') SS' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'GROUP BY Pk;';
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend for debugging
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Form;
DROP TABLE dbo.Item;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=464a5892cbbc5fd3b6addb9254089e2f)

Comment: Great work as always. Unfortunately while you were writing this up the OP cleared up they are working with 2012. :(

Comment: Yeah, I noticed @SeanLange :(. Why made sure I mentioned `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`, as at least they have access to the better Windowed function version.

Comment: Yeah should be an easy conversion to use Eirikur's extension to the original.

Comment: Thanks for this. While don't fully understand the code just yet, having problem where "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements." (The actual size of the domain table (`Item` in your example) is ~10,000). My thought for this is to break up the output into separate chunks / objects of the domain column values and link back together by the pk when pulling all the data into external applications. Would you mind showing how this would be done with your existing dynamic SQL code?

Comment: You'll need to add some kind of `WHERE` to the `SELECT` which uses `FOR XML PATH` @lampShadesDrifter . Truthfully, like I said, the important part is you understand what this does as it's up to you to support the SQL, not me (or anyone else on Stack Overflow).